# Trouble installing on localhost

Tags: installation

I am having trouble installing drupal on my localhost, using PHP Version 5.6.0-1, system Linux notosh 3.16-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.3-2 (2014-09-20) x86_64 
Installing standard 7.31, no distro.
Upon completion cannot login as user1 with password to access admin interface.

Comment: Please post the errors here which you are getting at login page?

Comment: If you have drush you can reset the password with, eg. `drush upwd --password=testpass testuser` (for username = testuser to change pass to testpass. Username must already exist.)

Comment: Thanks for answers. Attempting to login with user1 correct credentials fails, returns to same login page, incorrect credentials throw error. I already know what the cause is, PHP 5.6 alters the behavior of multibyte http string conversion. I am dealing with this issue at phpbuilder.com. You can find the whole thread there, by searching for my nick.

Answer (score 0):

I just used drush to install on localhost and it solved all my problems.
At present my PHP Version 5.6.4-1, it works fine.